# making sym link to executable file

Tags: c, shell, unix

I have a shell script **compileRun** that compiles and execute C source file.

```
#!/bin/sh
gcc bar.c -o ./bar
./bar
```

what i actualy  wish to achieve is when we

```
ln -s compileRun bar.c
./bar.c
```

I would like bar.c to be compiled and executed.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: You want *creation of a symlink* to implicitly run a compilation process? What leads you to believe this to be possible at all?

Comment: Frankly, any operating system that allowed it would be making questionable decisions on a security perspective, because someone *linking to a file* doesn't generally expect that in doing so they're implicitly running arbitrary code. As a matter of principle, arbitrary code execution is dangerous to have as a side effect.

Comment: ...that said, if you want `bar.c` to itself be executable, that *is* actually possible, just not with gcc. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tcc, enabling a `#!/usr/bin/tcc -run` shebang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what OP wants.

**What follows would work only if source files are explicitly stored in a different place than symlinks. A path can be prepended to `$0` in the bash script.**

Your should replace `somefile.c` by `$0` in your bash script.

This special shell expression returns the name of the file being currently executed. Which would be in your case, `bar.c`.

For example:

```
ln execute_c_file my_file.c
./my_file.c
```

If `my_file.c` is a running bash script `$0` will evaluates to `my_file.c`.

I suggest you edit your question to clear up the semantic/meaning of your code.

Comment: that almost fix my issue, but the problem is $0 is in ./myfile format.

Comment: It works only if sources are not in the same directory as symlinks.

Comment: @Samun You can prepend an absolute path to `./file`. Like `/home/./file` is equivalent to `/home/file`